# iOS Crash report Analysis - AppName[XXXX:XXXXX]

Tags: ios, iphone, logcat

When ever an app is in running state & any message is printed related to the app status, whether any NSLog(), or Crash report, or anything else... I observed there is a syntax which is as follows:

**2015-05-21 14:03:42.554 AppName[XXXX:XXXXX]**

Example:

**2015-05-21 14:03:42.554 TestApp[1234:12345] Message Print**

Can anyone tell me that what does the details in square brackets **AppName[XXXX:XXXXX]** means?

Answer (score 0):

The first number is the **process id**, and the second number is the **thread id**.

```
ISO8601Date AppName[PID:ThreadID] LogMessage
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate the terms **Process id** and **thread id**, that with what reference are these associated?

Comment: [The first thread created by fork(), PID=TID. If you create more threads within the process, with a clone() command, then PID and TID will be different, PID will always be smaller than TID.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19679063/3197253)