# Linux tgkill(), is it really possible to see two threads with the same tid?

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads

On Ubuntu Linux 20.04.4 (Linux kernel v5.13), `man tgkill` says:

> `int tgkill(int tgid, int tid, int sig);`
>
> tgkill() sends the signal  sig to the thread with the thread ID
> *tid* in the thread group *tgid*.

My question is, **can the system really have two threads with the same tid(acquired by `gettid()`)**, at a single moment?

If it can't, then why `tgkill()` force the user to provide the *tgid* parameter? The system should be able to query the corresponding `tgid` from a specific `tid` by himself.

BTW: I know that, to query `tgid` from `tid` (for example, 1554725) manually, we can `cat /proc/1554725/status` and grab the `Tgid` field.

The above statement can be verified using `threadtid.cpp` below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    (void)arg;
    int child_tid = (int)gettid();
    printf("Child:  tid=%d\n", child_tid);
    sleep(30);
    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1;
    int err = pthread_create(&t1, nullptr, threadFunc, nullptr);
    if (err != 0)
        exit(4);

    int parent_tid = (int)gettid();
    
    printf("Parent: tid=%d\n", parent_tid);

    void* childres = 0;
    err = pthread_join(t1, &childres);
    if (err != 0)
        exit(4);

    printf("Done.\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

We see that:

```
Name:   threadtid.out   
Umask:  0002            
State:  T (stopped)     
Tgid:   1554724  
Ngid:   0        
Pid:    1554725          
PPid:   37645      
...
```

[image]

Comment: pid/tid can be reused, which could be soon according to your system burden and task cycles.

At one monment, no 2 threads will share the same tid. But during the gap between the query (ps) and kill, the original thread could exit and new thread could reuse the same pid/tid.

Comment: I know that, but `tgkill`'s first `tgid` parameter does NOT solve the pid/tid reuse issue. TGID is actually the PID. So I think the `tgid` parameter is a redundant design.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't *solve*, just reduces the possible misuses .  The syscall handler will also check whether the caller is in same thread group or capable of "kill": https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6/source/kernel/signal.c#L856

Comment: `tkill()` is the obsolete predecessor of `tgkill()` without the `tgid` parameter and shouldn't be used.

Comment: "TGID is actually the PID" - This is not always the case. If one thread creates another thread, then created thread inherits tgid from the creator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9306150/3440745

Comment: [20240117.C1] To clarify: When I say "TGID is actually the PID". I mean the PID value from `getpid()`, not the `Pid` value from `/proc/TID/status` . Damn, we have to admit, on nowaday Linux , PID(abbr of process ID) becomes an ambiguous word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **can the system really have two threads with the same tid(acquired by gettid())**, at a single moment?

No.  Thread IDs are unique in the system *at any given time*, but they do get recycled.

Thread group IDs (and process IDs) are a subset of thread IDs (see [Relation between Thread ID and Process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19678954)), chosen situationally: the TID of the first thread of a new process is assigned as that thread's TGID and that process's PID.  When new threads are created in any other context, they inherit the PID and TGID of the thread that created them.  The distinction between PID and TGID suggests that Linus<sup>*</sup> may have anticipated allowing a process to have multiple thread groups, but to date, that has not been implemented.

> why `tgkill` force the user to provide the *tgid* parameter? The system should be able to query the corresponding `tgid` from a specific `tid` by himself.

The *tgid* parameter is not for identifying the thread to kill, *per se*.  A TID would be enough for the system to recognize a thread to signal, if it exists.  The TGID is to minimize the likelihood of the program signaling the wrong thread as a result of the one it meant having terminated, and its TID being recycled for a new thread.

With the TGID, that can only happen if the process to which that TGID belongs generates a very large number of threads itself.  Without, it can happen because of the behavior of other processes on the system, with no special privileges required of those other processes.  I can imagine that as an exploitable weakness.  I'm uncertain whether an actual exploit was ever created, but I note that Linux has an obsolete syscall `TKILL` that in fact does the same thing as `tgkill()` without requiring the TGID to be specified.  Linux rarely, if ever, actually removes syscalls, but `TKILL` should not be used, and Glibc does not provide a wrapper function for it.

---

<sup>*</sup>This is all Linux-specific.